# How do I remove a deleted but committed file from git?

Tags: git

I a have a file that has been moved from its folder, git sees this file as removed, so you run:

```
git add -u
```

This adds the deleted file to your 'Changes to be committed', I've tried to use:

```
git rm 
git clean -f and -n
```

Has anyone come across a similar issue? Here what the `git status` states:

```
git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  deleted: path/file.txt
```

I'm running Windows 8 with git bash.

Comment: Do you want to *undo the delete* or make the *delete be reflected in the history*?

Answer (score 1):

to commit changes, do `git commit`.

Comment: I've removed my upvote because of the new incorrect statement. "A commit after deleting the file from the working directory" *won't* delete it "from Git" as well. A commit after removing the file from _the index_ will.

Comment: I agree with you Charles, I would vote negative after the @Madara edition too ! just rolling back that to my 1st answer

Comment: Heh, sorry about that. Remember that you can always roll back changes you're not comfortable with. Take care.

Comment: No problem, I just discovered that function :) . Also, to really remove a file from the whole repository, this can be done with filter-branch , a good explanation here : https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to remove a file from the entire git history.

To do so, following the answer on the following page will help:

[Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)